# Navigating to a `defconst` variable defined by a Lisp macro

Tags: elisp-macros, macroexpansion

My goal is to define a const variable within a non-trivial macro that can be navigated to after calling `describe-variable`.

---

The design goal of my macro works just fine if I define it like so:

```
(defmacro test (symbol)
  `(defconst ,symbol nil))
(test sym)
```

After my init file loads I can navigate to the exact location in the file in which it was defined.

---

But the design goal of my macro does not work if I define it like so:

```
(defmacro test (symbol)
  `(defconst ,(intern (concat "jd:" (symbol-name symbol))) nil))
(test sym)
```

The const variable is defined, but I can't navigate to the exact location in the file in which it was defined (I only get so far as the file); instead I'm met with the message:
`Unable to find location in file`.

---

How can I achieve the design goal of my macro in the non-trivial case?